# Lifetime of element removed from global vector

Tags: c++, variables, member, lifetime

I basically have a

```
vector<Object> vec_;
```

as a class member in a cpp class. At a certain class function this vector will be filled with "Objects" just like this:

```
vec_.push_back(Object());
```

At a later time I iterate through the vector elements and keep a pointer to the best element. Then the vector is cleared as shown in the following:

```
Object* o_ptr = &(vec_[0]);
for (unsigned int i = 1;  i < vec_.size(); i++) {
  if (o_ptr->getCost() > vec_[i].getCost()) {
  o_ptr = &(vec_[i]);
} 

vec_.clear();
```

Now my question is: What happens to the objects removed from the vector? Is their lifetime over as soon as the they are removed from the vector? And does the pointer also point to empty space then?
And if not when does the lifetime of these objects end?

Regards scr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens to the objects removed from the vector?

They are destructed.

> Is their lifetime over as soon as the they are removed from the vector?

Yes.

> Does the pointer also point to empty space then?

Yes it does.  If you want to save the object, make a copy of it before clearing the vector.

It's also important to note that certain vector operations might leave pointers pointing to nothing even if the vector is not cleared.  Specifically resizes, which typically involve a reallocation.  It's generally best to store references to vector elements by index, since you will always be able to get the element via the index (whereas a pointer may be invalidated after certain operations).

The subscript operator, applied to vectors, returns a reference and does not make a copy.

Answer (score 3):

When `vector.clear()` is called (or when the `vector` is destructed) all objects contained with the `vector` will be destructed (as in this case they are objects and not raw pointers), leaving `o_ptr` as a dangling pointer.

Note that caching the address (or iterator) of an element in `vector` is dangerous, even without a call to `clear()`. For example, `push_back()` could result in internal reallocation of the `vector`, invalidating the cached address (or iterator).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to track the lifetime of an object is to add a printf to both the constructor and destructor.

```
class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject()
    {
        printf("MyObject constructed, this=%p\n", this);
    }
    ~MyObject()
    {
        printf("MyObject destructed, this=%p\n", this);
    }
};
```

Comment: You got this wrong in multiple aspects: Your class is not constructible (private constructor/destructor). You are missing a copy constructor (rule of three not obeyed as it should be for this task). With this setup, apart from the private ctor/dtor, you will easily see more destructions than constructions.

Answer (score 1):

The objects are owned by the vector and `.clear()` indeed removes them.

In addition, **pointing to the objects stored in a `std::vector` is a bit dangerous.** If you push new elements to the vector, at some point the vector might need to allocate more memory - which is likely to copy all the previous elements to a different address using their copy constructor (hence invalidating your pointers).

So: Use integer indices with `std::vector` instead of pointers, unless you know that you won't be pushing beyond the reserved capacity (which you can assure using `.reserve()`).

(Also while we're at it, make sure not to confuse the vector's internal buffer size with `.size()`, which is simply the number of actual elements stored).